# Is this correct use of .par in Scala?

Tags: scala

Below code computes a distance metric between two Users as specified by case class :

```
  case class User(name: String, features: Vector[Double])

  val ul = for (a <- 1 to 100) yield (User("a", Vector(1, 2, 4)))
  var count = 0;

  def distance(userA: User, userB: User) = {
    val subElements = (userA.features zip userB.features) map {
      m => (m._1 - m._2) * (m._1 - m._2)
    }
    val summed = subElements.sum
    val sqRoot = Math.sqrt(summed)
    count += 1;
    println("count is " + count)

    ((userA.name, userB.name), sqRoot)
  }

  val distances = ul.par.map(m => ul.map(m2 => {
    (distance(m, m2))
  })).toList.flatten

  val sortedDistances = distances.groupBy(_._1._1).map(m => (m._1, m._2.sortBy(s => s._2)))

  println(sortedDistances.get("a").get.size);
```

This performs a Cartesian product of comparison 100 users : 10000 comparisons. I'm counting each comparison, represented bu var `count`
Often the count value will be less than 10000, but the amount of items iterated over is always 10000. Is reason for this that as par spawns multiple threads some of these will finish before the println statement is executed. However all will finish within par code block - before `distances.groupBy(_._1._1).map(m => (m._1, m._2.sortBy(s => s._2)))` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have a single un-synchronized variable that you're mutating from multiple threads like you said. This means that each thread, at any time, may have a stale copy of `count`, so when they increment it they will squash any other writes that have occurred, resulting in a count less than it should be.

You can solve this using the `synchronized` function,

```
...
    val subElements = (userA.features zip userB.features) map {
      m => (m._1 - m._2) * (m._1 - m._2)
    }
    val summed = subElements.sum
    val sqRoot = Math.sqrt(summed)
    this.synchronized {
      count += 1;    
    }    

    println("count is " + count)

    ((userA.name, userB.name), sqRoot)
...
```

Using 'this.synchronized' will use the containing object as the lock object. For more information on Scala synchronization I suggest reading [Twitter's Scala School.](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html)

Comment: yes, .par itself is threadsafe, but mutating state outside of the function you pass .par is never threadsafe unless you explicitly guard it.

Comment: Alternatively, one could use javas `AtomicInteger` instead of `symchronized`.